# Capybara page.has_text? returning successful with wrong text?

Tags: capybara

Maybe im just using this wrong, because I was using Rspec's matchers previously (`expect(page).to have_content('foo')`)

However Im not sure which is really "best" to use, so I was trying to stick with mostly Capybara scoping if possible.

Anyways I have a basic piece of code that checks popup text on signin:
`page.has_text?('Signed in successfully.')`

Easy enough right? Well I can change the text to whatever, such as:
`page.has_text?('THIS IS WRONG')`

And it still passes? Am I just using it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [#has_text?](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_text%3F-instance_method) is just a boolean method, it will return true or false.  It is not an assertion, so unless you're checking whether the response is true or false it will not cause a test to fail.  If you want to check for the existence of text on the page with rspec you should be using exactly what you were previously using

```
expect(page).to have_content('expected text')
```

The `have_content` matcher (aliased as `have_text` too) is a matcher provided by Capybara designed for exactly what you are doing.
If you're not using RSpec anymore then you would do

```
page.assert_text('expected text')
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to one or the other (using page.assert vs expect(page) )

Comment: if using RSpec use the Rspec matchers since they'll provide better error mesages and there are more matchers provided for that than basic asserts - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers